# Calling a Scalar Function in a LINQ statement w/o an EDMX

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to call a SQL SCALAR function in EF.  I have tried various examples, but I keep getting:

> The specified method x on the type y cannot be translated into a LINQ
>   to Entities store expression.

**I am using...**

- EF 6.1.3
- EntityFramework.Functions 1.4.1

**THE QUERY:**
Notice I am calling it in the SELECT...

```
public IQueryable<MeterDataItem> Query()
{
    var query = from meter in UnitOfWork.Meter
                join meterType in UnitOfWork.MeterType on meter.MeterTypeId equals meterType.Id into meterTypeLEFTJOIN
                    from meterType in meterTypeLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join company in UnitOfWork.Company on meter.CompanyId equals company.Id
                join meterPosition in UnitOfWork.EFMMeterPosition on meter.EFMMeterPositionId equals meterPosition.Id into meterPositionLEFTJOIN
                    from meterPosition in meterPositionLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join flowType in UnitOfWork.FlowType on meter.FlowTypeId equals flowType.Id into flowTypeLEFTJOIN
                    from flowType in flowTypeLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join fluidType in UnitOfWork.FluidType on meter.FluidTypeId equals fluidType.Id into fluidTypeLEFTJOIN
                    from fluidType in fluidTypeLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join runStatus in UnitOfWork.RunStatus on meter.RunStatusId equals runStatus.Id into runStatusLEFTJOIN
                    from runStatus in runStatusLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join pipeline in UnitOfWork.Pipeline on meter.PipelineId equals pipeline.Id into pipelineLEFTJOIN
                    from pipeline in pipelineLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()

                // Device portion
                join device in UnitOfWork.Device on meter.DeviceId equals device.Id into deviceLEFTJOIN
                    from device in deviceLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join rtuDevice in UnitOfWork.RTUDevice on device.Id equals rtuDevice.DeviceId into rtuDeviceLEFTJOIN
                    from rtuDevice in rtuDeviceLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()

                // Contact portion
                join measureTech in UnitOfWork.User on rtuDevice.MeasurementTechnicianId equals measureTech.Id into measureTechLEFTJOIN
                    from measureTech in measureTechLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join commTech in UnitOfWork.User on rtuDevice.CommunicationTechnicianId equals commTech.Id into commTechLEFTJOIN
                    from commTech in commTechLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()

                // Connection portion
                join deviceCircuit in UnitOfWork.DeviceCircuit on device.Id equals deviceCircuit.DeviceId into deviceCircuitLEFTJOIN
                    from deviceCircuit in deviceCircuitLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join circuit in UnitOfWork.Circuit on deviceCircuit.CircuitId equals circuit.Id
                join circuitConnection in UnitOfWork.CircuitConnection on circuit.Id equals circuitConnection.CircuitId
                join connection in UnitOfWork.Connection on circuitConnection.ConnectionId equals connection.Id

                where
                    deviceCircuit.IsPrimary == true

                select new MeterDataItem()
                {
                    MeterId = meter.Id,
                    MeterNumber = meter.MeterNumber,
                    MeterName = meter.MeterName,
                    MeterTypeId = meterType.Id,
                    MeterTypeName = meterType.MeterTypeName,
                    MeterPositionCategory = meterPosition.EFMMeterPositionCategory,
                    FlowTypeName = flowType.FlowTypeName,
                    FluidTypeCategory = fluidType.FluidTypeCategory,
                    RunStatusCategory = runStatus.RunStatusCategory,
                    PipelineName = pipeline.PipelineName,
                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                    ConnectionValue = GetConnection(circuitConnection.Id, connection.ConnectionTypeName),
                    DeviceId = device.Id,
                    DeviceName = device.DeviceName,
                    MeasurementTechnicianId = measureTech.Id,
                    MeasurementTechnicianFirstName = measureTech.FirstName,
                    MeasurementTechnicianLastName = measureTech.LastName,
                    CommunicationTechnicianId = commTech.Id,
                    CommunicationTechnicianFirstName = commTech.FirstName,
                    CommunicationTechnicianLastName = commTech.LastName,
                    MeterObjectStateName = null,    //<-- Default Value
                    FavoriteId = 0                  //<-- Default Value
                };

    return query.OrderBy(x => x.MeterNumber);
}
```

**THE CSHARP-FUNCTION:**
I am guessing it cant find the function for some reason...

```
[Function(FunctionType.ComposableScalarValuedFunction, nameof(svfn_GetMeterConnection), Schema = "dbo")]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "VARCHAR(100)")]
public string svfn_GetMeterConnection([Parameter(DbType = "INT")]int circuitConnectionId, [Parameter(DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")]string connectionTypeName)
{
    ObjectParameter circuitConnectionIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("@CircuitConnectionId", circuitConnectionId);
    ObjectParameter connectionTypeNameParameter = new ObjectParameter("@ConnectionTypeName", connectionTypeName);

    return UnitOfWork.DbContext.ObjectContext().ExecuteFunction<string>(nameof(this.svfn_GetMeterConnection), circuitConnectionIdParameter, connectionTypeNameParameter).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

**THE SQL-FUNCTION:**
All my name & parameter name references look right...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[svfn_GetMeterConnection]
(
    @CircuitConnectionId INT,
    @ConnectionTypeName VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(100) = NULL;

    -- DIAL-UP
    IF(@ConnectionTypeName = 'Dial-Up')
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @Value = circuitConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionPropertyValue
        FROM [dbo].[CircuitConnectionConfiguration] circuitConnectionConfiguration
        JOIN [dbo].[ConnectionConfiguration] connectionConfiguration ON connectionConfiguration.Id = circuitConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionConfigurationId
        JOIN [dbo].[ConnectionProperty] connProperty ON connProperty.Id = connectionConfiguration.ConnectionPropertyId
        WHERE
            circuitConnectionConfiguration.CircuitConnectionId = @CircuitConnectionId
            AND connProperty.ConnectionPropertyName = 'Dial-Up Number'
    END

    -- INTERNET PROTOCOL (IP)
    IF(@ConnectionTypeName = 'Internet Protocol (IP)')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Value = 
            ((SELECT circuitConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionPropertyValue
                FROM [dbo].[CircuitConnectionConfiguration] circuitConnectionConfiguration
                JOIN [dbo].[ConnectionConfiguration] connectionConfiguration ON connectionConfiguration.Id = circuitConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionConfigurationId
                JOIN [dbo].[ConnectionProperty] connProperty ON connProperty.Id = connectionConfiguration.ConnectionPropertyId
            WHERE
                circuitConnectionConfiguration.CircuitConnectionId = @CircuitConnectionId
                AND connProperty.ConnectionPropertyName = 'IP Address') 
            + ':' +
            (SELECT circuitConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionPropertyValue
                FROM [dbo].[CircuitConnectionConfiguration] circuitConnectionConfiguration
                JOIN [dbo].[ConnectionConfiguration] connectionConfiguration ON connectionConfiguration.Id = circuitConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionConfigurationId
                JOIN [dbo].[ConnectionProperty] connProperty ON connProperty.Id = connectionConfiguration.ConnectionPropertyId
            WHERE
                circuitConnectionConfiguration.CircuitConnectionId = @CircuitConnectionId
                AND connProperty.ConnectionPropertyName = 'Port'))
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Value
END
```

**UPDATE - TO ANSWER:**
Some of the changes I needed include:

- Changing the function-type to FunctionType.ComposableScalarValuedFunction
- Changing the DbType parameter strings to Lowercase
- Making sure not to include the size in your DbType declarations: change VACHAR(50) to varchar
- Moving the calls into the concrete DbContext
- Registering the FunctionConvention in the concrete DbContext's OnModelCreating

**THE CONCRETE DBCONTEXT:**
Including namespaces...

```
using EntityFramework.Functions;
using StructureMap;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;

public class MeasurementContractsDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    #region <Constructors>

    [DefaultConstructor]
    public MeasurementContractsDbContext() : base(Settings.ConnectionString.Database.MeasurementContractsDb)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MeasurementContractsDbContext>(null);
        Database.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Settings.Command.TimeoutInterval]);
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region <Methods>

    [Function(FunctionType.ComposableScalarValuedFunction, nameof(svfn_GetMeterConnection), Schema = "dbo")]
    [return: Parameter(DbType = "varchar")]
    public string svfn_GetMeterConnection(int circuitConnectionId, string connectionTypeName)
    {
        ObjectParameter circuitConnectionIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("CircuitConnectionId", circuitConnectionId);
        ObjectParameter connectionTypeNameParameter = new ObjectParameter("ConnectionTypeName", connectionTypeName);

        return this.ObjectContext().ExecuteFunction<string>(nameof(this.svfn_GetMeterConnection), circuitConnectionIdParameter, connectionTypeNameParameter).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    [Function(FunctionType.ComposableScalarValuedFunction, nameof(svfn_GetCurrentObjectStateName), Schema = "dbo")]
    [return: Parameter(DbType = "varchar")]
    public string svfn_GetCurrentObjectStateName(int contextId, string contextFullName)
    {
        ObjectParameter contextIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("contextId", contextId);
        ObjectParameter contextFullNameParameter = new ObjectParameter("contextFullName", contextFullName);

        return this.ObjectContext().ExecuteFunction<string>(nameof(this.svfn_GetCurrentObjectStateName), contextIdParameter, contextFullNameParameter).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // ADD Functions
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention<MeasurementContractsDbContext>());

        // ...
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**SAMPLE USAGE:**

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Non-Existent 'Query' value throws this exception</exception>
public IQueryable<MeterDetailDataItem> AuthorizationToFlowMeterDocumentFilter(IQueryable<MeterDetailDataItem> query)
{
    if (query == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Query");

    string contextFullName = typeof(AuthorizationToFlowMeterDocument).FullName;

    // Get the ATF (if it exists)
    var filteredQuery = (from dataitem in query //<-- QUERY
                        join document in UnitOfWork.Document on dataitem.RequestToFlowMeterDocumentId equals document.ParentId

                         // TODO: Figure out if you can move svfn_GetCurrentObjectStateName into an Algorythm class that can be injected
                         // SQL Function
                         let objectStateName = ((MeasurementContractsDbContext)UnitOfWork.DbContext).svfn_GetCurrentObjectStateName(document.Id, contextFullName)

                        select new MeterDetailDataItem()
                        {
                            MeterId = dataitem.MeterId,
                            RequestToFlowMeterDocumentId = dataitem.RequestToFlowMeterDocumentId,
                            RequestToFlowMeterDocumentObjectStateName = dataitem.RequestToFlowMeterDocumentObjectStateName,
                            AuthorizationToFlowMeterDocumentId = document.Id,
                            AuthorizationToFlowMeterDocumentObjectStateName = objectStateName,
                            FirstDeliveryNoticeDocumentId = dataitem.FirstDeliveryNoticeDocumentId,
                            FirstDeliveryNoticeDocumentObjectStateName = dataitem.FirstDeliveryNoticeDocumentObjectStateName,
                            FavoriteId = dataitem.FavoriteId
                        });

    return filteredQuery.OrderBy(x => x.MeterId);
}
```

Comment: are you able to post minimal code for the types \ entities?

Comment: Try to write it with `let` keyword and than use that in your `select new`, so `...let cV = GetConnection(circuitConnection.Id, connection.ConnectionTypeName) select new … ConnectionValue = cV...`

Comment: @RandRandom - Didnt work

Comment: Just to make sure, you did call `AddFunction` as described here? https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Add_functions_to_entity_model

Comment: After reading this previous linked paged further, I believe I found your issue - you have declared your method `NonComposableScalarValuedFunction` which according to this page has the limitation `which cannot be used in LINQ to Entities queries;` what you want is a `ComposableScalarValuedFunction` see here how they are done https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Scalar-valued_function,_composable

Comment: Why are you loading all of you data with joins, doesn't that defeat the purpose of using ef

Comment: @johnny5 - No...using joins in a LINQ statement doesnt defeat the purpose of EF.  LINQ is built atop EF.

Comment: All the cartesian production for 15 joins, instead of just loading the loading the filtered data

Comment: @johnny5 The SQL is executed on the DB Server...it is NOT resolving it in the middle tier...thanks

Comment: @RandRandom - Do you happen to know where the Extension Method for AddFunctions is?  I am having trouble figuring that out.

Comment: Yes, but isn't there a lot more overhead for 15 join on SQL's end?

Comment: @johnny5 - (1) That is the ERD for the database is correct (2) The overhead on the DB is the same.  (3) If you can answer the question...great.  Otherwise, please stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using [EntityFramework.Functions](https://github.com/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions) package. Then take a look at [Function](https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#[Function]) topic. You are using **Scalar-valued function, non-composable**, which according to the package author

> can be called directly just like other above methods

but

> However, since it is specified to be non-composable, it cannot be translated by Entity Framework in LINQ to Entities queries

and

> This is by design of Entity Framework

While what you need is **Scalar-valued function, composable**, which

> works in LINQ to Entities queries, but cannot be called directly

Shortly, since you are using it inside LINQ to Entities query, use `FunctionType.ComposableScalarValuedFunction` inside `Function` annotation. And since it's not directly invokable, it doesn't need method body, so you can simply throw exception:

```
[Function(FunctionType.ComposableScalarValuedFunction, nameof(svfn_GetMeterConnection), Schema = "dbo")]
public string svfn_GetMeterConnection(int circuitConnectionId, string connectionTypeName)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

And don't forget to register the functions as shown in the link, otherwise they won't have effect and you'll continue getting `NotSupportedException`:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention<TheClassContainingTheFunction>());
```

Comment: Ivan, thanks for the answer.  I already tried this...but unfortunately, changing to "Composable" doesn't work either.  However, I will update my question to show this too.

Comment: Are you registering you custom functions as explained in the **Add functions to entity model** section of the same link? e.g. having `modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention<TheClassContainingTheFunction>());`?

Comment: Now getting "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String svfn_GetMeterConnection(Int32, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Comment: I'm using the same environment as yours and it works. May be it matters where the function is located. I've put it inside my db context, added `modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention<MyDbContext>());` inside `MyDbContext` `OnModelCreating` override, got some runtime errors that `INT`, `VARCHAR(100)` are not supported types, so I've removed the `Parameter` attributes, used the function inside query and it get's translated to SQL. So, is the function located inside your db context? If not, may be make it `static`?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case because all we want is to be translated to SQL. I've just replaced the body of the method with `throw new NotSupportedException();`.